# HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL using SpringBootServletInitializer

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I've just tried to upload my application to a server and it doesn't work, the page is not loading.

The console says "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (405)" and it appears an apache error with the message "HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL".

The strange thing is that locally works, running it with mvn spring-boot:run and with tomcat, so I don't know what may cause the problem.

My main class is this one:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "controllers")
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(applicationClass, args);
   }

   @Override
   protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
       return application.sources(applicationClass);
   }

   private static Class<Application> applicationClass = Application.class;
}
```

In order to run the application I enabled Java in the host and put the following code in the .htaccess:

```
SetHandler jakarta-servlet
SetEnv JK_WORKER_NAME ajp13
```

I tried adding doGet() and doPost() methods, but nothing happened. 
Whene I delete the files or the text inside the .htaccess it happens the same, so I don't know what might be. When I go to another page that is not the index it throws 404 error.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: also put you code with doGet and doPost here

Comment: I had them with an empty body because I didn't know what to put. I couldn't override them because SpringBootServletInitializer  does not implement them. What do I have to put in those methods?

Comment: Having the same issue when running with tomcat. Everything works locally.